# Is there an utility for editing the MS Search Server 2008 registry settings?

Tags: sharepoint, search, search-server

Microsoft Search Server 2008 and other MS serach products are tuned by editing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\12.0\Search\Setup\ContentIndexCommon registry key. Is there an utility for doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know off. I search the last couple of days, trying to find a decent answer for you here. Found none.